# Question on notation for a subfield generated by a set.

Tags: field-theory, notation

Let $S$ be a subset of $E,$ a field extension of a field $k.$ Apparently, $F = k(S) = Frac(k[S]).$ My question is:

1. Is $k(S)$ the smallest field that contains both $k, S?$
2. Is $k[S]$ the algebra over $k$ generated by elements of $S.$ That is, all polynomials over $S?$

Comment: Regarding point 2, there may be relations between the elements of $S$. In this setting, $k[S]$ is usually meant to be the smallest subring of $E$ containing $k$ and $S$; it will be a *quotient* of the polynomial ring over $k$ generated by $S$. (and it implicitly comes with the structure of being a ring extension of $k$ in a canonical way)

Comment: (the quotient, of course, being obtained by identifying a polynomial with its image in $E$)

Comment: Hmm wait sorry when you say quotient do you mean $k[X]/S?$