# A countable set of transcendentals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, transcendental-numbers

> Let $S$ be a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Prove that there is a real number $c$, such that $s+c$ is
> transcendental for all $s\in S$.

Any hint?

**Edit:** I was trying in vain to solve this by seeking algebraic properties of transcendental numbers.

Comment: let $F=\overline{\mathbb{Q}(S)}\cap\mathbb{R}$ be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(S)$ in $\mathbb{R}$. then $F$ is countable (why?), so in particular there exists some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\setminus F$. can you show that $\lambda$ has the desired properties?

Comment: What have you tried? It’s really true for most $c.$

Comment: Odd question: does this hold without AC? This seems to implicitly require 'the countable union of countable sets is countable'. (Although perhaps the explicit enumeration of algebraic numbers is enough to get the result even so)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom What is $\mathbb{Q} (S)$ in this context?  I'm not familiar with the rationals taking a set of reals as an argument.

Comment: dear @Alan, I mean the subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ generated by $\mathbb{Q}\cup S$ – see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2495989/question-on-notation-for-a-subfield-generated-by-a-set) for some discussion of the notation :)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Fix a single algebraic number $\alpha.$ How many $c$ are there so that $\alpha = s+c$ for some $s \in S$?